# How to create basic osx prefPane?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-snow-leopard

Long time reader, first time participant on StackOverflow :)

**disclaimer** I am *very* new to the mac development world.

I am trying to create a prefPane for a small daemon that has already been created.

I would like the prefPane to do two things:

1. Show the current status of the daemon ("started" or "stopped")
2. Provide a button to start/stop the daemon.

Can I use Interface Builder to make the interface and somehow have the prefPane use it? (Dumb question?)

Thanks for any tip/pointers on how/where to get started!

ps: I couldn't find a `prefpane` tag. If someone can tag this more appropriately I won't be offended :)

Comment: Xcode is just an IDE. The API you are referring to is named Cocoa.

Answer (score 2):

Making a prefPane isn't all too difficult. Just follow the examples [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/PreferencePanes/Tasks/Creation.html). And yes, you can use interface builder to make the interface.

Working with Launch Daemons is a much more difficult task. Check out [this](http://lists.macosforge.org/pipermail/launchd-dev/2009-December/000712.html) thread for starters. You can also create a NSTask wrapper around the "launchctl" command, with the verbs list, load and unload.

Comment: +1 for now; this is all a lot of information to take in. I'm going to do a bit of reading :)